# Is there an efficient/low-complexity extension of Gauss-Hermite quadratures to N dimensions where N is not too large?

Tags: integration, soft-question, numerical-methods

I should say that this question comes from an engineer who is not very familiar with the various techniques tackling numerical integration. I read some of the corresponding articles on wikipedia, but they do not provide sufficient details in order to answer my question.

Currently, I am using Gauss-Hermite quadratures to approximate a one-dimensional integral of the form 
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-y^2) f(y) \, dy \approx \sum_{i=1}^L w_i f(\xi_i)
$$
This turns out to be extremely accurate and efficient for the function $f(y)$ that I have, for example considering $L= 10$ values of the quadrature sum is absolutely fine, in the sense that increasing $L$ does not change much. The efficiency is rather important because I am using the result of this integral within an optimization routine. However, now I want to extend my problem to a more general case and then the above integral becomes four-dimensional. If I understood correctly, the straightforward extension of the Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule would then lead to an expression with four summations and thus I need to consider $10^4$ function evaluations of $f()$ to get the same precision. This, unfortunately, would render the numerical integration too complex for my optimization routine. Is there any way around this? Is there a more efficient extension of the Gauss-Hermite quadrature rule to such "moderate" dimensional problems? I already tried to apply a Monte-Carlo integration, which, however, turned out to be very unreliable for similar complexity as the one-dimensional case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you insist on having $10$ integration points for the desired accuracy in the one-dimensional case, then I'm afraid the answer is: _no_ . I think the only solution is: somewhat less desire.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The remark about the similar complexity as the one-dimensional case may have been a bit misleading. I do not insist on 10 integration point for the four-dimensional case. I am merely asking if there is anything with significantly less complexity than $10^4$.

Comment: I have only experience with Gauss (without the -Hermite) integration. This has turned out to be better than anything else I've tried. $N^d$ integration points are needed as well, where $d$ is the dimension. I haven't seen a way to avoid this.